# How to delete a node's parent using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following in my .csproj file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" ... ">
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="...">
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
   ...
    <Reference Include="abc, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..., processorArchitecture=...">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\xxx\xxx\5.0\abc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="def, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..., processorArchitecture=...">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\xxx\xxx\5.0\def.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ghi, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..., processorArchitecture=...">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\xxx\xxx\5.0\ghi.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>

    ...
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      ...
   </ItemGroup> 
</Project>
```

I have a list of DLLs in an array. I would like to find the DLLs of the array matching the DLL name in HintPath, and delete the corresponding Reference node if a match is found.

For example, if the array has abc.dll, then I would like the following to be deleted from the .csproj

```
<Reference Include="abc, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..., processorArchitecture=...">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\xxx\xxx\5.0\abc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Following is the code that I have, but it gives me an error - "Exception calling "RemoveChild" with "1" argument(s): "The node to be removed is not a child of this node.""

```
[xml] $pFile = Get-Content somefile.csproj

    foreach ($dll in $DLLarray)

    {

    $ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $pFile.NameTable
    $ns.AddNamespace('ns', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003')

    $nodes = $pFile.SelectNodes('//ns:HintPath', $ns)

          foreach($node in $nodes) 
        {

            $reference = $node.ParentNode
            $str = $node.get_innerXml()

            $regex = [regex] '(?is)(?<=\\)[^\\]+\.dll\b'
            $allmatches = $regex.Match($str)

            if ($dll -cmatch $allmatches)
            {   
                $pFile.RemoveChild($reference)                
                $pFile.Save($path)
            }


         }
```

Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$pfile` is the root node of the XML. You will need to get a reference to the `<ItemGroup>` element and remove the `<Reference>` node from there.

Possibly `$reference.ParentNode.RemoveChild($reference)`.

Comment: That worked fine, yeah now I see the mistake that I have made. Thanks!